# how to kill job in background?

Tags: shell, kill, background-process, jobs

I know how to kill a job with kill `%(number)` but is it possible to kill a job as background job, the question is  "kill `tail` as a background job?"

Answer (score 3):

There are several [ways to specify jobs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics), including `%foo` to designate the job whose command starts with `foo` and `%?foo` to designate the job whose command contains the substring `foo`. You need to specify an unambiguous prefix or substring: if more than one string matches, the shell reports an error. This is a POSIX feature.

```
kill %tail
```

(Note that this is specifically to kill a background job of the current shell. If you want to kill *all* `tail` processes running as your user regardless of whether they're a job of the current shell, you can use [`pkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html). Obviously, with a common utility such as `tail`, this could cause collateral damage; run the `pgrep` command with the same arguments first to see what would be killed.)

Answer (score 1):

Killing it like any other process should work:

`pkill tail`

Though if you want to be careful with that, you can check the PID with top, htop, or ps ahead of time.

Comment: so there is no such thing as killing a process in the background?

Comment: That kills **all** processes called `tail`, not just background jobs of the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this:

##### If you know the `<port>` number

```bsh
netstat -anp | grep :<port> | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F'[/]' '{print $1}' | grep -v "-" | xargs -I % kill -9 %
```

##### If you know the `<path>` to the file descriptor

```bsh
cat <path> | xargs -I % kill -9 %
```

##### If you know the `<process>` name

```bsh
pkill -f <process>
```

##### If you know partial process name as a `<pattern>`

Using `ps` and `grep`:

```bsh
ps -ef | grep '<pattern>' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

This will kill all the process that match with the `<pattern>`

Using `ps` with `awk`:

```bsh
ps -ef | awk '/<pattern>/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

This will kill all the process that match with the `<pattern>`